# convert fromtimestamp to datetime on list value of dict

Tags: python, datetime

```
[list([1618348860000, 63055.85, 63064.89, 63046.75, 63053.42, 14.126171])
 list([1618348920000, 63052.67, 63054.37, 63016.15, 63016.2, 15.611089])
 list([1618348980000, 63016.2, 63023.99, 63002.26, 63010.94, 12.159389])
 list([1618349040000, 63008.5, 63049.3, 63008.48, 63025.0, 22.189629])
 list([1618349100000, 63025.01, 63036.83, 63012.7, 63023.0, 17.94164])
 list([1618349160000, 63023.0, 63036.58, 62990.0, 63012.95, 19.76424])
 list([1618349220000, 63012.95, 63023.0, 63010.05, 63020.12, 10.362897])
```

Dictionary are like above and want to change first value to datetime format.

```
for row in dict:
    df[0][0] = datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

seems like I did not check something before I move on.

how can I get the dictionary that same but converted time?

Comment: could you please clarify, your example is a list of lists, how's that related to a dictionary?

Comment: `datetime` is a type, not a string, so it has no format. By converting the datetime value to a string you're almost in the same if not worse situation you were before- a non-date value that needs parsing before it can be used in calculations. It's worse because each locale has its own date format, so you need to ensure you use the correct pattern to parse the string, or end up with bad data. Formats apply only when parsing text data into strongly-typed dates, or formatting datetime values into strings for display, reports or storing in text files

Comment: Long story short, unless you intend to display those strings or save them to a file immediately, remove `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. Even better, don't modify the data in place. If anything goes wrong (early exit? off-by one index?) you'll be left with a dictionary where half the data are a UNIX timestamps, half are loocalized strings

Comment: Even better, don't use UNIX timestamps to store dates. It *doesn't* avoid the conversion issues caused by strings, it actually adds more of them. What's the precision? Second or millisecond? Worse, what's the timezone? And even worse, what happens with future dates? `fromtimestamp` doesn't work with dates after 2038 or dates before 1970. This means it can't record birthdates for example. All databases and languages have proper date types, so using a UNIX timestamp only causes problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos assuming the Unix timestamps stick to being (milli)seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC and here the integer milliseconds also represent their precision, I think they're useful in principal, no? Besides, if that's the input you get, that might be it and you have to deal with it... Although this is kind of off-topic, what data structure would you prefer instead to store date and time?

Comment: @MrFuppes no. They are not, because they're non-standard, limited and simply not needed. The range simply can't handle real world data - 1970 to 2038 is simply too short a range. What about birthdates? What about *your driver license expiration date*? Summer time? `what data structure would you prefer instead to store date and time` the date types used by the language and database. In Python `datetime` at least. Types with timezone offsets or even better, using IANA timezone names, are even better in many situations. Especially with HTTP APIs

Comment: @MrFuppes `if that's the input you get` that's rare, precisely because all languages, databases, and web services either have specific date types or (for JSON/SOAP) they use the ISO8601 format. One has to work to export dates as Unix timestamps. On top of that, the 2038 issue is well known. If Unix timestamps were common a lot of systems would already fail to handle date data. Banks would have trouble issuing housing loans for the last 3 years at least - such loans last 20 or 30 years. Never mind *business loans*

Comment: @MrFuppes speaking of banks, the big news in January 2020 weren't for COVID. Lloyd's and RBS had to shut down because they used hacks to cover up Y2K issues and keep using 2-digit years,  by assuming `20` and above meant 1920. Check [this](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/) and [this](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/). There's no excuse for ignoring the [Year 2038](https://www.theregister.com/2015/02/20/linux_year_2038_problem/) problem in 2021

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you should write a book about this, I'd buy it ^^ Seriously, valuable info, thanks.

Comment: @MrFuppes it's literally last year's news! By mid-January though (just two weeks later) we were in far bigger trouble

Comment: What is `dict` in `for row in dict` and what is `df[0][0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dict_1 = [list([1618348860000, 63055.85, 63064.89, 63046.75, 63053.42, 14.126171]),
 list([1618348920000, 63052.67, 63054.37, 63016.15, 63016.2, 15.611089]),
 list([1618348980000, 63016.2, 63023.99, 63002.26, 63010.94, 12.159389]),
 list([1618349040000, 63008.5, 63049.3, 63008.48, 63025.0, 22.189629]),
 list([1618349100000, 63025.01, 63036.83, 63012.7, 63023.0, 17.94164]),
 list([1618349160000, 63023.0, 63036.58, 62990.0, 63012.95, 19.76424]),
 list([1618349220000, 63012.95, 63023.0, 63010.05, 63020.12, 10.362897])]

for row in dict_1:
    row[0] = datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: @Yilmaz the for loop just change the format of the 0th item of each row in dict_1

Comment: Whenever you post an answer, explain what that codes does, so anyone reads your answer can understand.